# how to remove the " " inverted comes which are created in stringify function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

how to remove these inverted "" which are created automatically when i stringify a Json object.?

```
{"entityList":["{"Scenario No":"SC1","Accounting Mon Extracted":"null","Acronym":"null","Address1":"542","Address2":"null","AddressType
```

and then when the next Scenario starts there is another " " which is being created... i want it to be in this type so that i can post it over to the server...

```
{
  "entityList": [
    {
      "scenarioNo": "SC1",
      "accountingMonExtracted": null,
      "acronym": null,
      "address1": "542 W 27th Street 4th Floor",
      "address2": null,
      "addressType": "MAILING",
      "alternateEmailId": null,
      "alternateFaxNo": null,
     "alternatePhoneNo": null,
      "city": "Bethlehem",
      "country": "US",
      "county": null,
      "firstName": "Thomas",
      "fullName": "Peter Jen",
      "lastName": "Routher",
      "middleName": null,
      "namePrefix": null,
      "nameSuffix": null,
      "primaryAddressYN": "Y",
      "primaryEmailId": "johnmann@yahoo.com",
      "primaryFaxNo": "(406)485-2983",
      "primaryPhoneNo": "(405)452-3645",
      "state": "AB",
      "zipCode": "40007.0",
      "agentType": null,
      "autoCommClosingDays": null,
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,
      "creditTermMonths": null,
      "customerNo": null,
      "doingBusinessAsName": null,
      "eftDraftOption": null,
      "entityType": "INSURED",
      "frequencyDayMonth": null,
      "frequencyDayOfWeek": null,
      "frequencyType": null,
      "invoiceCurrency": "USD",
      "ncanGraceDays": null,
      "outputDeliveryMethod": "M",
      "parentEntityCode": null,
      "paymentMethod": "EFT",
      "process1099Indicator": "N",
      "recurringEFTTokend": null,
      "requestedDueDay": null,
      "sourceSystem": "DPAS",
      "sourceSystemEntityCode": "INS000020",
      "statementFormat": null,
      "statementIndicatorYN": "N",
      "statementMailingDay": null,
      "userRemarks": null,
      "vendorCode": null,
      "ssn": null,
      "taxid": null
    },
    {
      "scenarioNo": "SC2",
      "accountingMonExtracted": null,
      "acronym": null,
      "address1": "542 W 27th Street 4th Floor",
      "address2": null,
      "addressType": "MAILING",
      "alternateEmailId": null,
      "alternateFaxNo": null,
      "alternatePhoneNo": null,
      "city": "Bethlehem",
      "country": "US",
```

My Code in javascript is as follows...

```
var row = {};
var insured=[];
var a;
var row1 = {};
var insured1=[];
var a1;
function creatJsonobj(){
    var cols = $("#policytable thead tr th").map(function(){ 
        return $(this).text()
    })
    var tableObject = $("#policytable tbody tr").map(function(i) {

        $(this).find("td").each(function(i) {
            var rowName = cols[i];
//            console.log(rowName);
            row[rowName] = $(this).find('input').val();
            a= JSON.stringify(row);
        })

//        console.log("entity table : "+a);

        insured.push(a);
//        console.log(insured);                  
        return row;
    }); 
    for(var i in insured){
        var cli = JSON.parse(insured[i]);
//        console.log(cli);
    }

    var entityObj = {entityList: insured} ;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(entityObj).replace(/\\/g, ''));


     $("#entityTable").empty();
      var cols1 = $("#paymenttable thead tr th").map(function(){ 
        return $(this).text()
    })
    var tableObject = $("#paymenttable tbody tr").map(function(i) {

        $(this).find("td").each(function(i) {
            var rowName = cols1[i];
//            console.log(rowName);
            row1[rowName] = $(this).find('input').val();

            a1= JSON.stringify(row1);
        })
//        console.log("payment table : "+a1);

        insured1.push(a1);

        return row1;
    }); 
    for(var i in insured1){
        var cli = JSON.parse(insured1[i]);

    }

    var paymentObj = {paymentList:insured1} ;
/*    var C=JSON.stringify(sendJson1);
    var finalData = C.replace(/\\/g, '');
alert(finalData);
    console.log(finalData);*/
     console.log(paymentObj);

    var billing = {entityObj,paymentObj};
    console.log(billing);
```

How to do so....??

Comment: You can use `""` instead of `null` and issue solved

Comment: `a= JSON.stringify(row);` should happen outside of your `.each()` loop.

Answer (score 1):

When you stringifyied `row`, it's now a `string`, not a `object`.

Your way:

```
var row = JSON.stringify({key:value}); // which return a string
var object = {entityList: [row]};
console.log(JSON.stringify(object)); // which inputs "{entityList: ["{"key":"value"}"]}"
```

Right way:

```
var object = {entityList: [row]};
console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
```